# When using Facebook Folly in my code, g++ could not find some header

Tags: c++, facebook

I have installed Facebook Folly from source, and some headers were copied to `/usr/local/include/folly` automatically.

Then I am using `#include "folly/Conv.h"` in my code, but when I compile, I meet a error: `could not find folly/CpuId.h`.

I find that `CpuId.h` is not in `/usr/local/include/folly` but it is in the directory where I downloaded Folly.

My questions:

1. Why doesn't Folly copy all headers to `/usr/local/include/folly` when I installed it?
2. How can I know my Folly version? I just downloaded the `folly-master.zip` without `git` some day before installing it.

Answer (score 0):

> why does not folly copy all header to /usr/local/include/folly when I installed ?

Some version is not so good as others. I met with the same problem too. It's quite stable now.

> how can I know my folly vertion? I just download the folly-master.zip without git someday before.

It has [several releases](https://github.com/facebook/folly/releases).

If you are using Gentoo Linux, you may employ [my folly library overlay](https://github.com/mapx/gentoo-overlay).